# Raised more flags than total flags

Tags: discussion, support, flags, flag-history

I raised 342 flags and in that

- deemed helpful     = 227
- declined           = 9
- disputed           = 18
- waiting for review = 5
- Total              = 259

So here out of 342 flags it showing count of 259 then what about remaining 83 flags

[image: Flag summary]

Comment: Look  a bit down there should also be comments and such stuff, these count also to the total amount

Comment: check my edit @Rizier123 , including posts and comments even not covered total of raised flags

Comment: I'm not too sure, but then  I think your other flags "aged away". So you don't see them on the right list. Just go back a bit and look if you find any flags, which are "aged away".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under those nice stats you can see a note:

> older flags were not recorded helpful/declined

These are visible in the list as [*aged away*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204347), but they are tracked in the totals only.